There are $n$ pairwise disjoint red edges or $n$ pairwise vertex-disjoint blue triangles in a $K_{4n-1}$.
I found the following problem while learning more about Ramsey theory:

Let $R(nK_3, nK_2)$ denote the smallest integer $N$ such that any
red/blue-colouring of the edges of $K_N$ contains either $n$ pairwise
disjoint red edges or $n$ pairwise vertex-disjoint blue triangles.
Prove that $R(nK_3, nK_2) = 4n - 1$.

The solution manual however proposed a solution different from mine. That is, it first bounds $R(nK_3, nK_2)$ from below and above. The former is quite easy and for the latter, it uses induction aswell, but their approach seemed spacious compared to mine. Such discrepancy makes me believe that my proof has some holes I don't see since I am new to the topic. Any help/hint is therefore appreciated.
My solution:
We proceed by induction on $n$. For $n=1$ we have $R(3,2) = 3 = 4*1-1$.
Thus we have $K_3$ which is either a blue triangle or otherwise has at least one red edge.
Assume now $n \geq 2$ and the claim holds for smaller $n$ and consider an red/blue-coloring of $K_{4n-1}$.
Since $n \geq 2$, $K_4 \subset K_{4n-1}$.
Consider any set $S$ of $4$ vertices and let $G$ be a graph induced by $S$, i.e, $G = K_4$.
Let $G' = K_{4(n-1)-1} = K_{4n-1} - S$ and by induction hypothesis, $G'$ has either $n-1$ pairwise disjoint red edges or $n-1$ pairwise vertex-disjoint blue triangles.
Note that the latter is indepedent by the colouring of the edges we removed from $K_{4n-1}$ to obtain $G'$.
If any edge in $G$ is now colored red, $K_{4n-1}$ has $n$ pairwise disjoint red edges, since we only consider the colouring of the edges in $G$ and not between $G$ and $G'$.
Otherwise, all the edges in $G$ are colored blue and thus, $G$ has a blue triangle that is vertex-disjoint from any blue-triangle in $G'$.
Again, we only consider the colouring of the edges in $G$ and not between $G$ and $G'$.
Thus $G$ has $n$ pairwise vertex-disjoint blue triangles.
This completes the proof.
Thanks in advance!

I added the solution-verification tag since that's your intent. Per the description, please "identify precisely which step in the proof is in doubt, and why so. "

To be honest, I can't pinpoint exactly where I doubt my proof; its just that I'm still unfamiliar with the topic and proof techniques for it as a whole and unfortunately I have no opportunity to validate my solution anywhere else. I don't believe it to be wrong, but I also don't know if I'm missing anything.

Unfortunately, your solution doesn't work.
Like you said, "by induction hypothesis, $G'$ has either $n-1$ pairwise disjoint red edges OR $n-1$ pairwise vertex-disjoint blue triangles." We do not know which one, neither can we assume that it is both.
You later say "If any edge in $G$ is now colored red, $K_{4n-1}$ has $n$ pairwise disjoint red edges", But (based on your current reasoning) that is only true IF we assume that $G'$ has $n-1$ disjoint red edges.
To continue your argument, what you'd likely have to do is split into cases based on what $G'$ contains.
Case 1: IF we assume that $G'$ has $n-1$ disjoint red edges....
Case 2: IF we assume that $G'$ has $n-1$ disjoint blue triangles ...
However, as a warning, I don't see a quick way to complete the solution from here. IE For case 1, what happens if $G$ is all blue edges? How do we show that there's $n$ disjoint red edges or $n$ disjoint blue triangles?

I've tried to come up with another solution considering your points in another answer.

I figured something was off. Maybe this solution works:
We proceed by the induction step: Let $n \geq 2$ and consider a red-blue coloring $c$ of $G = K_{4n-1}$. Let $S \subset V(G)$ be a subset of any $4$ vetices in $G$. If $G[S]$ contains at least one blue triangle and at least one red edge, we are done by applying the induction hypothesis onto $G - S$. We first assume that $G$ has no blue triangle. In particular, there is no blue triangle in $G[S]$ nor $G - S$. Thus, by induction hypothesis, $G - S$ has $n − 1$ disjoint red edges and $G[S]$ has at least one red edge. Thus $G$ has $n$ red disjoint edges. If $G$ has a blue triangle, we may assume that the edges incident to the vertices of such triangle are only colored blue as otherwise we found a proper subset $S$. Consider now such blue triangle on $\{x,y,z\} \subset V(G)$ and let $G ' = G - \{x,y,z\}$. If $G'$ has no red edge, then all edges in $G$ are colored blue and we can pick any $4$ vertices to apply the induction hypothesis and show that $G$ contains $n$ vertex-disjoint blue triangles. If $G'$ has at least one red edge, say $uv \in E(G'), u,v \in V(G')$, then it is incident to a blue triangle in $G$. W.l.o.g., $\{x,y,u\}$ induces a blue triangle and $u$ is adjacent to $v$ via a red edge. Hence, we found a proper $S$ in $\{x,y,u,v\}$.
